# How to optimize sql where = (select from same_table)

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have a PostgreSQL query and I wonder if there are any ways to optimize it.

The main bottleneck in the query is a sub-query, I think.

```
select social_status, count(*)
from client
where 1 = 1
  and social_status = (select social_status from client where id = 1)
  and created_at between '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp - interval '14 day' and '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp
group by social_status
```

Also, I've tried to replace `=` with `in`, but it didn't change anything.

I've tried to use join, but it returns nothing:

```
select a.social_status, count(*)
from client a
JOIN client b
     ON a.id = b.id
where 1 = 1
   and b.id = 1
  and a.social_status = b.social_status
  and a.created_at between '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp - interval '14 day' and '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp
group by a.social_status
```

Right now it takes around 13-19 seconds.

explain (analyze, buffers, format text) result:

```
QUERY PLAN
GroupAggregate  (cost=8.44..206659.09 rows=12 width=17) (actual time=23584.356..23584.357 rows=1 loops=1)
  Group Key: a.social_status
  Buffers: shared hit=8737 read=183781
  I/O Timings: read=22802.316
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using client_id_index on client  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=9) (actual time=1.405..1.407 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 1)
          Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
          I/O Timings: read=1.374
  ->  Seq Scan on client a  (cost=0.00..206645.81 rows=943 width=9) (actual time=202.157..23582.677 rows=2323 loops=1)
        Filter: ((created_at >= '2018-08-27 06:05:41'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((social_status)::text = ($0)::text))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 812931
        Buffers: shared hit=8737 read=183781
        I/O Timings: read=22802.316
Planning Time: 0.217 ms
Execution Time: 23584.460 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: The sub-query is not the issue (it takes about 1.5 milliseconds) Do you have an index on `created_at`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think, there is no index for this field, but I can't change the db unfortunately.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the missing index on that column is the main reason for the slow query. If you want that to be faster, you'll have to create the index

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do that. But the initial query doesn't require any optimizations?

Could you please add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using window functions:

```
select social_status, count(*)
from (select c.*,
             max(social_status) filter (where id = 1) over () as social_status_1
      from client c
     ) c
where social_status = social_status_1 and
      created_at between '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp - interval '14 day' and
                         '2018-09-10 06:05:41'::timestamp
group by social_status;
```

For this query, you want an index on `client(id, social_status)` and `client(created_at, social_status)`.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't provide the correct result, unfortunately. I need to get a count of social_status that is set for specific client. With your approach I get counts for all types of social_status.

Comment: @Alex . . . I fixed the query.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I think, the main issue is that there is no index for created_at, as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned. I'll try to fix it within my company.